# jQuery load/dynamic content best practise

Tags: jquery, load

We have a web app, which is tab structured. When a user clicks a tab for the first time, it loads in content via .load(). This is great and works well and is relatively fast, however we want to cache the load so in future, if the user clicks the same tab as before, it doesnt load the content in, it just .show() the same content as before.

For example:

```
$('#link1').click(function(){ 
    $('#holder1').load('/pages/link1');
}
```

How can i store that the user has loaded the content in and just show the content on next click. I need to keep it as modular and universal as possible, so not just link1, link2 etc...

Any ideas?

Comment: If you use jQuery UI Tabs, you get content caching for free. http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#ajax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mmmm....

you should create an array  q dictionary on your JS which is like this :

**userId      LinkId      Content**

each load you should put the value in there

and the next time you need to load something - check it first on the dictionary / qarray.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep a flag if data is loaded, then check flag again to avoid reload, I am using custom attribute(data-) here.

```
$('#link1').click(function(){ 
 if($('#holder1').attr('data-loaded')!='yes')
 {
    //data is not loaded then load
    $('#holder1').load('/pages/link1');
    $('#holder1').attr('data-loaded','yes')
 }else
 {
    //data is already loaded then just show or do something else
 }
}
```

Comment: You know you can just call `$('#holder1').data('loaded')`, right?

Comment: Yup, but sometimes old practice takes time to go away, thanks :)

Comment: Fair enough!  It's a rather new addition that `.data` loads from the HTML5 attributes.  1.6, I believe?

Comment: "As of jQuery 1.4.3 HTML 5 data- attributes will be automatically pulled in to jQuery's data object. The treatment of attributes with embedded dashes was changed in jQuery 1.6 to conform to the W3C HTML5 specification."  http://api.jquery.com/data/

Answer (score 0):

Just to throw out another thought, if your dynamic information is being loaded, say, into the DOM or populating some HTML on the page, you can simply test to see if that HTML exists prior to making your AJAX call to populate it!  Consider the case of tabs, where clicking on "#tab2-link" populates "#tab2" and activates it:

```
$('#tab2-link').click(function() {
    tabLoader(this.id.split('-link')[0]);
});

function tabLoader(tabId) {
    var $tabId = $(tabId);
    if($tabId.html() === '') {
        $tabId.html('<img src="spinner.gif" />'); //Add/show a spinner
        $tabId.load(...); //Remove/replace your spinner on AJAX success.
    }
    $tabId.show();
}
```

This I would say is the most common approach to this sort of thing, and by far the easiest.